# Sitecore 8 MVC Glass Query Datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

It seems like query datasources (ex: query:...) are not supported in Sitecore 8 MVC while using glass. I want to make a relative path so that branch templates will point to the correct datasource when created. Is there a way to do this with Sitecore's query builder? I saw the custom query option where a path can be specified but couldn't seem to get anything going. I think I might add a pipeline processor before the model gets bound by glass to change a datasource that starts with `query:` into a resolved path and pass that along the pipeline arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood. Datasource queries are supported in Sitecore 8 MVC, this has nothing to do with Glass, which itself [supports queries](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial7). As long as your query is resolved to a correct item then the item should be passed to Glass. Can you provide same of the code/branch structure that you are using?

Comment: Maybe I'm just using it incorrectly. Do you know how to give a view rendering's datasource a query that gets an item that is a child of the current item with the name Test Content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a datasource query to a `Sublayout` or `Rendering` `Datasource Layout` field. You will need to add a new `Processor` to the `getRenderingDatasource` `Pipeline`. I myself have used this on `Branch Templates` to make relative paths to the correct datasource.

Your `query:.` needs to be defined in the `Datasource Location` of the sublayout/rendering and make use of `ancestor-or-self` to make relative paths and traverse the tree to find the parent item holding the datasources.

```
query:.ancestor-or-self:: *[@@templatename = 'home']/*[@@templatename = 'storage']/*[@@templatename = 'articles']
```

The processor will need to use the `GetRenderingDatasourceArgs`. These arguements will provide you pretty much everything you need. Essentially you will need to get the `query:.` you wrote in the `Datasource Locations`.

```
args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"];
```

Replace the beginning of the query with the Context Item path (so that its relative) and then make a call to get the items;

```
private IEnumerable<Item> GetDatasourceLocationsFromQuery(string query)
{
    string queryPath = query.Replace("query:.", args.ContextItemPath);
    return args.ContextDatabase.SelectItem(queryPath);
}
```

This will then return the matching item that is the parent of the datasources.

Comment: Alright that makes sense to me. I think I might do a check to see if that starts with `query:`. If it does then I'll remove `query:` and run it as a Sitecore query and return the first item selected from that.

Comment: From experience it does require query:. rather than query: